# Difference between "besichtigen" and "besuchen"

Tags: word-usage, difference

What is the difference between *besichtigen* and *besuchen*?

> Wir haben viele Museen besichtigt.
>
> Ich werde morgen Berlin besuchen.

Comment: A simple view in some dictionary should resolve this and make also clear why your second sentence is not really good. Weil das, was *besichtigt* wurde, strenggenommen und üblicherweise nicht das Museum selbst ist, sondern die Ausstellung bzw. die Exponate, die im Museum gezeigt werden. Ausnahmen sind Freilichtmuseen.

Comment: So is besuchen just going there and besichtigen more like observing and taking in what you see? Also, dict.cc does offer up "ein Museum besichtigen" as an example, but in my Stilwörterbuch the examples seem to be more like inspecting (das Baby, die Truppe, die Wohnung b.)

Comment: @Ingo Ich denke schon, dass man ein Museum besichtigen kann. Die Ausstellungen sind ja teil des Museums. Würde man mit dem Begriff Museum nur das Gebäude ansich bezeichnen, hättest du recht. - Genau genommen passt "besichtigen" theoretisch in beiden Sätzen (wobei ich es in beiden Sätze, so wie sie jetzt da stehen, nicht verwenden würde - aber das hat andere Gründe). Besuchen hingegen passt imho in keinem der Sätze, aber aufgrund des Englischen "to visit a museum" wird's wohl keiner anmakeln. - Von dem Standpunkt eine berechtigte Frage, auch wenn natürlich die Recherche fehlt (@DerPolyglott33).

Comment: @thekeyofgb Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Em1 Sicher, meist wird aus dem Kontext klar, was gemeint ist. Es mag aber Museen geben, die in Gebäuden untergebracht sind, die selbst einer Besichtigung wert sind. Da wird es dann unklar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Das Wort „besuchen“ kann fast alle Bedeutungen des englischen Verbs „to visit“ übernehmen und ist damit bei Übersetzungen eine sicherere Wahl. Hingegen beschreibt „besichtigen“, dass man sich etwas ansieht, und dass man sich dazu dorthin begeben hat.

> Ich werde morgen Berlin besuchen.

Das heißt also, dass Du noch nicht in Berlin bist, morgen aber dorthin fährst, um dort für eine  Weile, aber nicht dauerhaft, zu bleiben. Der Grund ist wahrscheinlich touristischer Natur.

> Ich werde morgen Berlin besichtigen.

Das heißt hingegen, dass Du Dir die Stadt, also zum Beispiel ihre Architektur, tatsächlich ansehen möchtest. Dabei kann es sein, dass Du jetzt bereits in Berlin bist, aber vielleicht im Hotel sitzt. Besuchst Du Berlin, um abends in Klubs zu gehen, besichtigst Du die Stadt nicht.

> Wir haben viele Museen besichtigt.

Das ist nicht völlig falsch, ich würde es aber nicht sagen. Üblicherweise besucht man ein Museum, um dort eine Ausstellung zu besichtigen. Zu sagen, man besichtige das Museum, hört sich so an, als man wäre mehr an dem Museumsgebäude interessiert (was ja durchaus vorkommen kann).  Man kann auch sagen:

> Wir haben die ständige Ausstellung im Kunstmuseum besucht.

Und wie gesagt:

> Wir haben das Kunstmuseum besucht und dort die ständige Ausstellung besichtigt.

Hingegen ist folgender Satz nicht optimal:

> Als wir im Kunstmuseum waren, haben wir dort die ständige Ausstellung besucht.

Man war ja schon da, musste also nicht mehr anreisen. Diesen Einwand werden aber einige als kleinlich empfinden.

**Zusatz:** Natürlich besucht man auch Personen. Diese zu besichtigen wäre hingegen sehr ungewöhnlich, es würde implizieren, sie wie ein Museumsstück zu behandeln.

Answer (score 6):

You can use both words in both contexts without any significant shift in meaning, but there's a slight difference though.

**Besichtigen**

[Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/besichtigen) describes this word as:

> irgendwohin gehen und etwas (genau) ansehen, um es kennen zu lernen.

This means, you visit a place in order to take a thorough look at something. Example: if you're going to move somewhere and you visit apartments and houses to figure out which one you want to buy or rent, then this is called *besichtigen*.

Both your examples, visiting a city or museum, are valid use cases for *besichtigen*. For some reason that I cannot name, I wouldn't use *besichtigen* in collocation with a concrete city name. But I guess this is just a personal thing.

**Besuchen**

Wiktionary describes this word as:

> 1: jemanden aufsuchen, um mit ihm eine Weile zusammen sein zu können
>   2: zu einem Ort gehen, um dort jemanden zu treffen oder etwas zu erledigen
>   3: etwas für eine gewisse Zeit regelmäßig aufsuchen

All these three definitions have something in common: you go somewhere to do something specific. This is quite a superficial definition and thus visiting a city is among the "something specific". But again it bothers me personally to use something like "Berlin besuchen". It's not quite what I think of when I say that I *visit something*. But I've heard something like *eine Stadt besuchen* or *ein Land besuchen*, so it definitely is in use. Oddly enough that *ein Museum besuchen* sounds even more weird to my ears but *Besuch eines Museums* sounds fine.

I guess my point is: you can use both words in both contexts if you prefer. It's not to everyone's taste but it's valid German. There's a subtle difference in its precise meaning but the final result is the same: you visit a city or museum.